# My HP notebook keyboard has no function keys visible

Tags: hp-pavilion, function-keys

My HP notebook doesn't have any function keys, so how do I push <kbd>F10</kbd> without an F10 key? I tried using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and pressing the number keys but nothing happened.

Comment: Which notebook model is it? Do you have and F-key printed on the existing keys? A picture of the keyboard would help as well.

Comment: What model laptop? What does the keyboard look like?

Comment: So we can help you, please turn the notebook over and find the model number on the same plate or sticker as the serial number. That's the model number specific to your hardware; any model number on top, on the screen bezel or above the keyboard is normally a marketing series name and there can be dozens of different models with that same series name. Then, once found, click on `edit` above and to the left and add that model number to your original post. We must have that to find useful information to help you.

Comment: Its most likely that you have special function buttons, for like brightness and volume etc. They probably have small text written on them named F1 to F12. Hit fn + those keys to get the assigned F-key. But as stated by above, without the type of your notebook, we can't know for sure. And don't forget, you can ALWAYS plugin an external keyboard that does have the F-keys.

Comment: Or use the onscreen keyboard if running Windows.